# Why can I not login to Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I quit and restarted Minecraft because it was being slow/lagging a lot to see if it would help.

Unfortunately, when I opened it up I was logged out and every time I try to login it gives me this message:

> Username or password incorrect!

So, I re-typed everything and made sure to type it all correctly and it still won't let me log in. I also noticed that as soon as I hit login the password becomes blank.

I have purchased the game so it's not like a trial has expired or anything like that. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried redownloading it and logging in again?  Maybe your launcher has become corrupted or something.

Comment: Are you using the full download version, not the demo?

Comment: no its not the demo, its the full game

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the new launcher, (I'm assuming you are) just click the "Which do I use" link underneath the "Email Address or Username:" box, or the "Forgot Password" link under the "Password" box.

Answer (score 0):

That's interesting... I have 2 ideas though, that might work:

1) have you tried going to minecraft.net, testing out the password and username then copying and pasting it on minecraft?

2) have you also tried selecting a new profile on minecraft? or making a new one to get out?

I had the same problem but these 2 things worked for me... Maybe it will work for you to